# How to solve my problem of max_step parameter in pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I'm trying to train source code.

```
class mymodel(pl.LightningModule):
  def __init__(self, config , learning_rate = 1e-4, max_steps = 100000//2):
    super(mymodel, self).__init__()
    
    self.config = config
    self.save_hyperparameters()
    self.training_losses = []
    self.validation_losses = []
    self.max_steps = max_steps

  def configure_optimizers(self):
    return torch.optim.AdamW(self.parameters(), lr = self.hparams['learning_rate'])


  def forward(self, batch_dict):
    return answer_vector

  def calculate_metrics(self, prediction, labels):
      batch_size = len(prediction)
      ac_score = 0

      for (pred, gt) in zip(prediction, labels):
        ac_score+= calculate_acc_score(pred.detach().cpu(), gt.detach().cpu())
      ac_score = ac_score/batch_size
      return ac_score

  def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    answer_vector = self.forward(batch)
    loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(answer_vector.reshape(-1,self.config['classes']), batch['answer'].reshape(-1))
    _, preds = torch.max(answer_vector, dim = -1)

    train_acc = self.calculate_metrics(preds, batch['answer'])
    train_acc = torch.tensor(train_acc)

    return loss

  def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    logits = self.forward(batch)
    loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(logits.reshape(-1,self.config['classes']), batch['answer'].reshape(-1))
    _, preds = torch.max(logits, dim = -1)

    ## Validation Accuracy
    val_acc = self.calculate_metrics(preds.cpu(), batch['answer'].cpu())
    val_acc = torch.tensor(val_acc)

    ## Logging
    self.log('val_ce_loss', loss, prog_bar = True)
    self.log('val_acc', val_acc, prog_bar = True)
    
    return {'val_loss': loss, 'val_acc': val_acc}

  def optimizer_step(self, epoch_nb, batch_nb, optimizer, optimizer_i, opt_closure = None, on_tpu=False,
    using_native_amp=False, using_lbfgs=False):

        ## Warmup for 1000 steps
        if self.trainer.global_step < 1000:
            lr_scale = min(1., float(self.trainer.global_step + 1) / 1000.)
            for pg in optimizer.param_groups:
                pg['lr'] = lr_scale * self.hparams.learning_rate

        ## Linear Decay
        else:
            for pg in optimizer.param_groups:
                pg['lr'] = polynomial(self.hparams.learning_rate, self.trainer.global_step, max_iter = self.max_steps)

        optimizer.step(opt_closure)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
```

In 5'th epoch (maybe less or more) I encountered error that stop training. so I increase max_step . But when I increase max_step(max_step==100K) I have this problem with loss and acc that
loss>100 && acc==0 .I attach screen of this problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQdK0.png)

What changing I should do in source code to continue training model without this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Updates:
I see. It looks like your `optimizer_step` is actually for "scheduler," where it messes with the AdamW learning rate. You should directly apply the scheduler to `configure_optimizers` function. See https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/lightning_module.html?highlight=configure_optimizers#configure-optimizers

===
old answer:
By error, do you mean the line of `val_ce_loss`? If yes, that's not an error. It means the `val_ce_loss` of the current epoch is not within the top1 of historical epochs so the checkpoint won't be saved to the disk. Please refer to the argument of `save_top_k` in the checkpoint callback. https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pytorch_lightning.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint.html

Comment: No No @joe32140 .I mean part of acc & loss . Let me to describe more about running and source. I have 5000 data and 2 batch and I want to run that model for 1000 epoch in 50000 max_step but when I run this training stop in 20 epoch (maybe more or less) and that cause is max_step so I increase max_step to 1000000 and training doesn't stop but loss became a thousand times and acc became 0 and its not reasonable. 
 (I have to just 2 batch because when I increase batch mare than 2 I encounter error out of memory)
Do you think when I change max_step I should change other parameters?

Comment: I see. It looks like your `optimizer_step` is actually for "scheduler," where it messes with the AdamW learning rate. You should directly apply the scheduler to `configure_optimizers` function. See https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/lightning_module.html?highlight=configure_optimizers#configure-optimizers